# Insertar lista a una consulta Postgresql Python

Tags: python, postgresql, tablas

Tengo una lista con ids de registros d una tabla de mi base de datos.

Y quiero que la consulta haga un 'IN' sobre los elementos de una tabla.

Este es mi codigo

```
tabla = ['61542', '60864', '60865', '60742', '60837', '60838']

cur = open_lnk.cursor()

cur.execute("select * from tabla where id in %s") % tabla
```

Y este es el error que me tira:

```
    cur.execute("select * from stock_production_lot where id in %s") % A0101
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «%»
LINE 1: select * from stock_production_lot where id in %s
```

Con diccionarios no tengo problemas porque indicaria

```
cur.execute("select * from tabla where id in %(clave)s") % diccionario
```

Trabajo con python 2.7.6

Comment: Me sorprende que te funcione con diccionarios. ¿Puedes añadir a la pregunta cómo es ese diccionario? Estás confundiendo el operador formato `'%'` de python con el modo de pasar parámetros a un consulta DB-API2. Te aconsejo que revises algunos ejemplos de la documentación del módulo postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fué mas mundana de lo esperado, simplemente creé un string con la consulta y después simplemente se la pasé como variable al ORM:

```
consulta = ("select * from tabla where id in %s") % tabla

cur.execute(consulta)
```